# django login required for the entire site not working

Tags: python, django, django-views, django-settings, django-middleware

I am trying to use a code to force login if a user is not authenticated yet. I have tried too many codes and I could not get them working since most of them written in older versions of django. I am using django 1.10.3.

I am not getting any errors when running the server, but I am not getting redirected to the login page too while I am not logged in. I am not even sure we can have both MIDDLEWARE AND MIDDLEWARE_ClASSES in the setting file. Any help would be appreciated. I also would like to have exceptions where I can make some of the views public that requires no login

**middleware.py:**

```
from builtins import hasattr, any
from django.http import HttpResponseRedirect
from django.conf import settings
from re import compile

EXEMPT_URLS = [compile(settings.LOGIN_URL.lstrip('/'))]
if hasattr(settings, 'LOGIN_EXEMPT_URLS'):
    EXEMPT_URLS += [compile(expr) for expr in settings.LOGIN_EXEMPT_URLS]

class LoginRequiredMiddleware:
    """
    Middleware that requires a user to be authenticated to view any page other
    than LOGIN_URL. Exemptions to this requirement can optionally be specified
    in settings via a list of regular expressions in LOGIN_EXEMPT_URLS (which
    you can copy from your urls.py).

    Requires authentication middleware and template context processors to be
    loaded. You'll get an error if they aren't.
    """
    def process_request(self, request):
        assert hasattr(request, 'user'), "The Login Required middleware\
 requires authentication middleware to be installed. Edit your\
 MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES setting to insert\
 'django.contrib.auth.middlware.AuthenticationMiddleware'. If that doesn't\
 work, ensure your TEMPLATE_CONTEXT_PROCESSORS setting includes\
 'django.core.context_processors.auth'."
        if not request.user.is_authenticated():
            path = request.path_info.lstrip('/')
            if not any(m.match(path) for m in EXEMPT_URLS):
                return HttpResponseRedirect(settings.LOGIN_URL)
```

**setting.py:**

```
MIDDLEWARE = [
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
    'heaven.LoginRequiredMiddleware',
]
```

Comment: If you have the `MIDDLEWARE` setting, Django will ignore your `MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES` setting.

Comment: I moved  'heaven.middleware.LoginRequiredMiddleware', to MIDDLEWARE and deleted MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES. It gives me this error: File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py", line 82, in load_middleware
    mw_instance = middleware(handler)
TypeError: object() takes no parameters

Comment: Check your indentation for `assert` under `def process_request`

Comment: It needed indentation and i fixed it,but still I get no errors, but still it does not ask the user to login

Comment: You need to convert it to new-style middleware as outlined in the documentation.

Comment: @knbk I read the documentation, but still I cannot figure out what the difference is in the new-style. Also I tried to use a simpler code (I replace the code in the question), but still no luck, my web app works, but it does not make the user to login when using any view

Comment: The easiest solution is to [inherit from `django.utils.deprecation.MiddlewareMixin`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/http/middleware/#upgrading-middleware).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Django changed middleware logic at Django 1.10 . Django 1.10 has a new approach.
[here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/http/middleware/#upgrading-middleware)

My middleware class. It is working

```
# Below middleware class for Django1.10
  class StatisticMiddleware:
      def __init__(self, get_response):
          self.get_response = get_response
      # One-time configuration and initialization.

      def __call__(self, request):
          # Code to be executed for each request before
          # the view (and later middleware) are called.

          response = self.get_response(request)

          self.__model_object_statistics(request, response)

          return response
      def __model_object_statistics(self, request, response):
          # My algorithms
```